# jquery variable won't change to false in php even though in the console is changing

Tags: php, jquery

I just encountered a weird bug.

I'm checking if a checkbos is checked or not using JQUERY-AJAX and then i'm sending the value ( true of false ) to my php file.

I'm checking the console and when the checkbox is ticked , the value of my variable "preferEmail" is changing to "true" and vice versa .

But then in PHP , it always sees it as ticked, even when it's not , and i can see in the console that the JQUERY validation is working fine.

The weird part is that it worked fine a couple of times, and then it stopped working and i haven't touched the code.

I need the value of $errorEmptyPreferEmail to change to "true", when $preferEmail is false , but it always stays false.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="../php/contact.php"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="mail-repair" name="email-me" value="prefer-email">
<button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button place-button">SEND</button>
</form>
```

```js
 // everything is working fine here , "prefer-email" is the name of my input type="checkbox"

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contact-form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
 
 var preferEmail = false;   // initialising the checkbox as false ( meaning not checked)
 if($('input[name="prefer-email"]').is(':checked')){  
 // if this condition is met then i change the value of preferEmail to true
                  preferEmail = true;
                  console.log(preferEmail);  // checking if the code is running properly
              }
               else{
                  console.log(preferEmail); 
              }       

 $.ajax({
url: "../php/contact.php",
type: "POST",

data: {                           
                preferEmail: preferEmail,
                submit: submit},
success: function (event) {
    $('#hidden').html(event);      }
});

   });
    });
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$preferEmail = $_POST['preferEmail'];
$errorEmptyPreferEmail = false;
if ( $preferEmail != true ) {
    $errorEmptyPreferEmail = true;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('validated');</script>";
}
}
```

If in my php file I do :

```
elseif ( $preferEmail == true ) {
    $errorEmptyPreferEmail = true;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('validated');</script>";
}
```

The alert always pops up , even when $preferEmail is false in the console .

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ajax send true or false to PHP as a string type.

method_1 : in PHP you could change true to "true" in conditions like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$preferEmail = $_POST['preferEmail'];

$errorEmptyPreferEmail = false;
if ( $preferEmail !== "true" ) {

    $errorEmptyPreferEmail = true;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('not validated');   </script>";
  }elseif ( $preferEmail === "true" ) {
    $errorEmptyPreferEmail = false;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('validated');</script>";}}
```

or method_2: first convert your data into json type

```
$.ajax({
url: "res.php",
type: "POST",

data: {                           
                preferEmail: JSON.stringify(preferEmail),
                submit:JSON.stringify(submit)
               
            
            },
```

and decode them in PHP :

```
$submit = json_decode($_POST['submit']);
$preferEmail =  json_decode($_POST['preferEmail']);
```

Comment: I've already got a function, I've added it now

Comment: ok i think i found out. the js send true or false to PHP as a string type. so in PHP you can change true to "true" in conditions like this : if ( $preferEmail !== "true" )

Comment: thanks so much man you absolutely smashed it. btw , i didn't decode it in PHP with  "$preferEmail =  json_decode($_POST['preferEmail']);" , left it as a string cus when i decoded it , it didn't work . And i only did stringify on "preferEmail" only , i left the rest of the variable that i was posting as normal